# What's the assumption in Banach-Steinhaus proof that says $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n = X$?

Tags: functional-analysis

What's the assumption in Banach-Steinhaus proof that says $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n = X$?

Where

$$X_n=\{x \in X : \sup_{T \in F} \| T(x) \|_Y \leq n \}$$

As given in the proof here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle

I don't understand how taking mere supremums of some transformation can fill in some arbitrary Banach space.

I understand that it says that "for all $x$ in $X$ one has". But I don't understand why does this imply that the whole of $X$ is an union of supremums.

Comment: The pointwise boundedness assumption.

Comment: @MisterRiemann Where's that?

Comment: You're assuming that for each fixed $x\in X$, you have $$ \sup_{T \in F} \Vert Tx \Vert <+\infty, $$ i.e. that the collection is pointwise bounded.

Comment: What do you mean by "union of supremums"? For each $x\in X$, you will have $\sup \Vert Tx \Vert \leq n$  given that $n$ is large enough (since you're assuming that this supremum is *finite* for each $x$), and so $x \in X_n$ for large enough $n$. Since you can do this for any $x$, the $X_n$'s fill the whole space.

Comment: @MisterRiemann $\{ x \in X : \sup \|Tx\| \leq n \}$ I read means that such $x$ that this property holds. However, why does "$x$s that satisfy finite supremum in $T$" mean that the whole of $X$ is an union of those $x$s? Is this some idea regarding that "because this implies that $T$ is continuous, then it must 'traverse' all possible $x \in X$"?

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: @MisterRiemann Also what does pointwise boundedness say about the $x \in X$?

Answer (score 3):

One of the hypotheses of the theorem is that $F$ is pointwise bounded.  That is, for each $x\in X$, $$\sup_{T\in F}\|T(x)\|_Y<\infty.$$  So in particular, for each $x\in X$, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\sup_{T\in F}\|T(x)\|_Y\leq n,$$ i.e. $x\in X_n$.

Comment: Okay this makes it clearer. So because every $x$ of $X$ is in some $X_n$, then the union must be all $X$.